# Recommended Animated Model Format to Load in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, model

What is the recommended animated model format that a game programmer would load in OpenGL?

I have taken a look at .md2 and .3ds formats available at some OpenGL tutorials. However, it would appear that they are both fairly old. Is there any well-supported model format that a contemporary game programmer would prefer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're a beginner, you should probably start with those formats. (Or maybe MD3, which comes after MD2.) Newer 3D formats don't typically supercede old ones by being objectively better, but usually by supporting more complex features. I'd recommend not making life difficult for yourself by picking a complex format.

If you're not a beginner, then you probably wouldn't be asking this question. ;) Professional developers usually have a bespoke model type that is specific to the engine they're using.

If you have specific requirements for your models then it's possible that there exists a model format that fits your needs, but MD2 and MD3 worked fine for commercial games so they'll probably work fine for you too. Generally you should approach this from the other side - what sort of models can my artists create, or what sort of models can I obtain? What format are they in? Can I use that format?

Comment: How this got broad answer got checked is beyond me...

Comment: The other answer isn't much more specific. :) My experience of OpenGL is that there is no single recommended format.

Comment: I hear ya. I think the problem is the lack of documentation to the things most people inquire about. You would think OpenGL and DirectX would by now have good documentation on achieving common tasks, but it's been evident that they aren't investing much of anything into keeping anyone up to speed on the basic 'How-to' sector. Generally, they are  telling new pilots to fly their new jets with an under-par flight manual. Their lack of importance on the tech manual side is discouraging, which is why most young developers stick to 2D.

Comment: MD2 / MD3 is a rubbish recommendation. What's the point of investing any amount of time in supporting a model format on the import / render side when there's absolutely NO current support for creating / exporting in any significant modelling application?

Comment: Feel free to post an alternative. Or, just get an exporter the way we usually did: http://www.katsbits.com/tools/#md3

Answer (score 2):

[ms3d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MilkShape_3D#MilkShape_3D_file_format) seems quite common. (there are links to the format on that page).
[FBX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX) is another. There is no good documentation for the format but there is an SDK to load it. On directx .x files would be another option but that's probably not so much use ofor opengl. (And it's not really that well supported on directx any more).

The most common format though seems to be to define your own application specific format that contains just what you need and use an exteral converter to convert to that format.